# Номер записи таблицы в sql запросе

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как определить номер записи в таблице sql запросом?
К примеру, есть таблица, в ней надо изменить последнюю запись, только запись должна быть последней по номеру (RecNo).

Answer (score 6):

В СУБД нет никаких номеров записей. Есть уникальные идентификаторы. Отслеживать последнюю строку - это уже ваша задача.

Например, если идентификатор - число, можно получить идентификатор последней строки:

```
select max(id) from my_table
```

MSSQL умеет возвращать идентификатор последней добавленной записи кажется так:

```
select @@scope_identity
```

Кроме того, можно использовать в таблице поле типа TIMESTAMP для поиска последней измененной или добавленной записи. В любом случае реализация этой логики ложится на разработчика.

Answer (score 2):

Например если у вас уникальный идентификатор - int autoincrement, то последнюю запись всегда можно вытянуть запросом `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`
А вообще **Notafe** прав, никаких номеров записей в СУБД нет, вы сам творец своей БД :)